# Unable to start ChromeDriver in CI environment

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with ChromeDriver in .NET Core. All tests work fine locally, however fail in TeamCity with the following error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 24272
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

...

OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:24272/
```

After the tests have finished, `chromedriver.exe` isn't terminated. There is nothing in the Windows event log or further details in the build logs, so I'm now stabbing in the dark.

I am using the following arguments, some added out of desperation:

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("--no-first-run");

// See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");

Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Interestingly, the remote debugging port != the port in the first error. Not sure if this means anything. The [Chromedriver documentation](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) suggests that options are added without leading `--`, but removing this doesn't seem to have any effect.

FWIW the TeamCity agent is running as a local Windows service account on Windows Server 2008 R2 (yes, I know).